# All about liferay configuration with ldap server

Tags: ldap, liferay-6

I am new to liferay.
I want to configure LDAP server with liferay 6.1 GA 2.
Can someone please let me know what are the steps i have to follow?
I only know how to set up liferay on my local machine but i have no idea for further procedure.
Any help would be appropriated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it's a lot of stuff you'll need to do I'd start with :

1. Setting an LDAP server (except you're gonna need to connect to an existing one)
2. Spend some time understanding the LDAP binding mechanism (there are different modes like anonymous binding, bind with admin and search etch)
3. install some software to browse the LDAP directory
4. think what kind of authentication routine are you going to have. Are you going to export users to LDAP ? are you going to import too ? Will the users be able to change their passwords from the protal ? If the LDAP auth fails, will they be authenticated with the portal's passwords
5. Understand the meaning of the liferay's LDAP specific parameters. Some parameters are set fro portal-ext.properties, while some other are defined by Portal admin's console (Portal Settings/Authentication) You'll have to think how the Liferay's User and User Group attributes are going to match the LDAP's one
6. Take into account the Liferay's bugs on LDAP. Many versions fix some bugs while introducing new ones
7. Gradually configure Liferay to bind with LDAP. Check and test the LDAP server binding, the User and UserGroup scanning. Test misc scenarios (import user, create a new one from protal registration, auth with LDAP server down, etc)

Generally, don't be hasty to jump into, take some time to study, because it will save you lots of time

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at the [Liferay User Guide](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide), there is a part which explains the [LDAP Setup](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/ldap).

This blog post might also be helpful: http://www.opensourceforlife.com/2012/05/liferay-61-ldap-config-from-portal.html

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue about export password to LDAP:

- https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-43045

Answer (score 0):

There is an open bug about passwords only being updated in LDAP if the password is stored unencrypted in Liferay's db: [Export user password in LDAP when user is created](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-4608)

Comment: is this in 6.1 GA 2 still an issue?